# Multiple Content Search Web Parts 2013 Bug

Tags: 2013

I've encountered the following issue with the Content Search WP which occurs when more than one CSWP is on the page. The following single threaded mode error occurs sporadically. ULS logs throw no further light on the issue, and it really appears random. Appears to be a MS bug - I'm hoping the latest CU will resolve the issue but there is no mention of this in the release notes.

Any ideas?

"Attempted to make calls on more than one thread in single threaded mode (EXCEPTION from  HRESULT 0x80010102 (RPC_E_ATTEMPTED_MULTITHREAD))"

Answer (score 4):

Appears that the March SharePoint server PU update has fixed this.